# SELECT Mysql com resultado errado

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Vamos pegar a tabela abaixo como exemplo:

```
id  empresa  forneedor
    1   10       105
    2   10       102
    3   10       105
    4   10       112
    5   10       105
```

Usando empresa e fornecedor como índices.

Fazendo `SELECT * FROM table WHERE empresa = 10;` -> retorna 5 linhas que é o esperado.

Fazendo `SELECT * from table WHERE fornecedor = 105;` -> retorna 3 linhas que é o esperado.

Fazendo `SELECT * from table WHERE empresa = 10 AND fornecedor = 105;` -> retorna apenas 1 linha, resultado **não** esperado.

A tabela está no formato INNODB

Já utilizei o comando OTPIMIZE TABLE, mas não resolveu.

Alguém faz idéia de onde está o problema?

---

Já detectei que o problema está ocorrendo com tabelas particionadas e index_merge.
Creio que é um problema similar a este https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70588.

Comment: Você consegue criar um [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) reproduzindo este problema?

Comment: Post your problem in: stackoverflow.com

Comment: Será que você não quer o operador `OR` ao invés de `AND`

Comment: Eu diria que é impossível , um bug destes já teria sido reportado e corrigido, verifique tipagem das  colunas , se o registro realmente existe , síntaxe (um distinct no lugar de um "*") etc. , repito , seria um erro tão crasso que alguém já teria reportado , impossível isto em um SGBD com milhões de usuários e instalações. Deveria ter dito improvável mas me  arrisco no impossível mesmo. abs

Comment: Motta, aceito sua opinião, concordo, mas sim está ocorrendo. É um fato isolado em uma base de teste, então não estou desesperado. Mas não estou conseguindo corrigir. Já restaurei o backup do banco oficial. Problema persiste, já recriei as chaves da tabela. Problema persiste. A mesma query sendo executada em meu banco oficial retorna as linhas corretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido.

Atualizada a versão do MySQL para 5.6.19 (era 5.5.?).

Problema com tabela particionada e múltiplos índices. Mais informações aqui [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70588)

Obrigado aos que tentaram ajudar.